# PHP session variable appear to change on it's own

Tags: php, session, session-variables

Very weird, I hope I'm simply overlooking a small detail. I've combed through this line by line for days, but I'm still at a loss.

So when my page loads, I set a random variable to `$_SESSION['rand_token']`, I then place that value in a hidden field in my form. When the form is submitted, I check the session value against the post value and if they match, I handle the form submission, if they don't match, I continue loading the page (which means the form is not processed and the session variable gets changed again, and the hidden form input gets the new session variable).

The problem is that the session variable is changing sometime in between when the last line of code executes and when the second line of code (the 1st line is `session_start();` executes (after a form submission). I have `print_r($_SESSION);` at the beginning and end of the code to see this.

Why is the variable changing!?

```
<?php 
session_start(); 

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';

if (isset($_SESSION['rand_token'], $_POST['rand_token'], $_SESSION['rand_token_expires'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['rand_token'] == $_POST['rand_token'] && time() < $_SESSION['rand_token_expires']) {
        //Process form
    } else {
        $danger_msg = 'Token Mismatch<br />Post: ' . $_POST['rand_token'] . '<br />Session: ' . $_SESSION['rand_token']; 
    }
}

$_SESSION['rand_token'] = md5(microtime(TRUE) . rand(0, 100000));
$_SESSION['rand_token_expires'] = time() + 60 * 60 * 1;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
?>

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?=$_SESSION['rand_token']?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**I'll show you the results after 2 subsequent submissions:**

1st print_r: 4ff3d097a6a760a4c579f8d8a5b355ed

Token Mismatch Post: fd6bf788ed3d1393b087472f41b3efd1

Token Mismatch Session: 4ff3d097a6a760a4c579f8d8a5b355ed

2nd print_r: 053f22d6126130e88f355fbc5cbbde1f

---

1st print_r: 279a85854fc6362d8dc52b0b74d30ef7

Token Mismatch Post: 053f22d6126130e88f355fbc5cbbde1f

Token Mismatch Session: 279a85854fc6362d8dc52b0b74d30ef7

2nd print_r: edbee2d6cedbf5581920af353754fed8

I know this is a little confusing to follow, but you'll see that the 2nd `print_r` should be the same as the next 1st `print_r`. Why is it changing?!

Comment: 1) Could you post your code (use pastebin if it's really to large)?
2) How can you check the value of your session vs the post value if you're using the post to replace it in the first place? That sounds like a 100% match. Could be wrong but I lack the code to understand the problem.

Comment: I think you've been a member on Stack long enough to know that you should include code in a question such as this.

Comment: I don't see how a variable could change itself.

Could it be that caching or server setting / firewalls are actually serving stale tokens and not new ones every time?

Comment: After reading your post a couple of times I finally seem to understand what you're trying to do and I'm wondering why? You can use PHP to simply check if any $_POST[''] value is empty and simply reload the HTML form if needed. You can even pass values back to the form that were filled so the user doesn't have to fill those again.

Comment: @icecub I've included the code above. I'm checking them against each other to prevent someone from refreshing the page after they've submitted the form. this way, it prevents the form from being submitted because the hidden input value won't equal the new session value.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You're absolutely right. I figured because I can't see the problem in the code, it wouldn't help.

Comment: @EddSmith The new token is actually unique, it's not a stale token. I've tried clearing the cache and starting the session from scratch, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: @icecub I'm checking the session variable against the post variable because I don't want someone to be able to submit the form and press refresh. That would submit the form twice. This way, if they don't match, the form submission is ignored.

Comment: I'm thinking, since you've a POST variable and using `<input type="hidden" value="<?=$_SESSION['rand_token']?>"` try using `<input type="hidden" value="<?=$_SESSION['rand_token']?>" name="rand_token"` then changing your `form` to `<form method="post">` since form defaults to GET when not including a method, that could be part of the problem.

Comment: Another thing I thought of is, make sure short tags are enabled. If they are not, then use `value="<?php echo $_SESSION['rand_token']?>"` instead of `value="<?=$_SESSION['rand_token']?>"`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for your insight. In my code I did have the things you mentioned... Sorry for not copying the code properly. In any case, I side-stepped this problem by dealing with refresh submissions in another way completely: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: @SolidI I'm glad to hear you found your solution However, sometimes code isn't always required when it comes to general questions, this one did (sessions can be quite tricky), *cheers*. ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not really an answer but there were some mistakes in your code. I've updated it and it's working perfectly fine:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';

if (isset($_SESSION['rand_token'], $_POST['rand_token'], $_SESSION['rand_token_expires'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['rand_token'] == $_POST['rand_token'] && time() < $_SESSION['rand_token_expires']) {
        echo "Form should be submitted.";
    } else {
        $danger_msg = 'Token Mismatch<br />Post: ' . $_POST['rand_token'] . '<br />Session: ' . $_SESSION['rand_token']; 
        echo $danger_msg;
    }
}

$_SESSION['rand_token'] = md5(microtime(TRUE) . rand(0, 100000));
$_SESSION['rand_token_expires'] = time() + 60 * 60 * 1;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
?>

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action=""> <!-- forgot to set form to post here, defaulted to get instead -->
    <input type="hidden" name="rand_token" value="<?=$_SESSION['rand_token']?>" /> <!-- forgot to set name="" here -->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the actual code, my form does have method and action set, and the hidden input does have a name.

If they didn't the token mismatch wouldn't display "post" value.

Comment: Well I'd love you help you out but if you test this code, it's working exactly as expected. I can't fix what isn't broken. Only way to solve you problem is having access to your actual code I guess.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time, I've sidestepped this whole thing by using a PRG process. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 0):

I recently experienced the same thing and in my case, specially for tokens generated with time functions, if one of the assets calls 
on the page returns 404, it apparently regenerates the token. So check if the page has calls for assets returning 404.